# Display array loop php

Tags: php

For some reason I really can’t output an array. Can you help please

```
<?php foreach ( $feature as $b=>$features_collapsee): ?>
    <?php var_dump($features_collapsee) ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

displays

```
string(12) "1 GB - 1 €" array(2) {
   [0]=> array(2) { ["features_collapse_title"]=> string(22) "Interneti maht paketis"
         ["features_collapse_description"]=> string(4) "0 GB" }
   [1]=> array(2) { ["features_collapse_title"]=> string(5) "lorem"
                  ["features_collapse_description"]=> string(5) "lorem" } }
```

i want display

```
Interneti maht paketis

0 GB


lorem

lorem
```

Comment: What is the second part of your snippet?

Comment: That is array from var_dump . I want display it with echo

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php 

 $data = array(
   array(
    "features_title"=>"Internet Eestis",
    "featrues_description"=>"1 GB - 1 €",
    "features_collapse"=>array(
        array(
       "features_collapse_title"=>"Interneti maht paketis",
       "features_collapse_description"=>"0 GB"
       ),

      array(
       "features_collapse_title"=>"lorem",
       "features_collapse_description"=>"lorem"
       )
    )
  )
 );

 foreach ($data[0] as $key=>$value )
 {
  if(is_array($value)){
    foreach($value as $t){
        echo $t['features_collapse_title']."<br>";
        echo $t['features_collapse_description']."<br>";
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in`
it's return warning second foreach

Comment: @Kaiserr try it again

Comment: It's return only `Internet Eestis` i want return all

Comment: try echo $features_collapsee->features_collapse_title; and features_collapsee->features_collapse_description

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213709/discussion-between-hardood-and-kaiserr).